# How to retrieve the current user's token_auth for Piwik API request?

Tags: matomo

I recently started experimenting with Piwik plugins and came over the task to download some statistics as CSV. No problem, using an API request.

The target group of this plugin is not very affine to computers, so I'll have to add a button "download CSV" within Piwik. To do so, I added a Report plugin. Now, I need the user's `token_auth` to create the query string. How do I get it?

As the user can retrieve the `token_auth` from the user management, I (a) consider it's possible and (b) do not see severe security issues in using it. But how? Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, someone else is looking for the answer, here it is:

The token is displayed in the user management, but only via a translation `{{ token_auth }}` in the template (.twig) file. Further searching in the `View` class finally lead me to the method, I was searching ([Reference](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/Piwik/Piwik#getcurrentusertokenauth)) to access the current user's token via PHP script.

```
\Piwik\Piwik::getCurrentUserTokenAuth()
```